# How to do a regex negative lookahead in a ee.String.replace()?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
var someText = ee.String("1_2_text").replace('(?:\\d_)*(?!\\d)','').aside(print)
```

I would expect `1_2_` to be matched and replaced with nothing. Instead I am getting the following error:

```
String (Error)
String.replace: Invalid regular expression: '(?:\d_)*(?!\d)' (invalid perl operator: (?!).
```

which is very confusing, since I don't even use Perl. I guess Earth Engine uses Perl behind the scenes, even though this isn't documented anywhere, but anyway, Perl supports negative lookaheads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly Perl, it's that the lookahead operator you're trying to use is part of an extended regex expression language commonly referred to as PERL-re.  Earth Engine uses RE2 instead (in which that operator isn't supported).

If you're just looking to match and replace any leading numeric+underscore prefixes, I think this should get you there:

```
.replace('^([0-9]+_)*', '')
```

Comment: I probably should have guessed Earth Engine uses RE2. It would be nice if this would be explicitly documented. It would be extra nice if the error message would explicitly say ```(invalid RE2 operator: (?!)```. I submitted this feedback to the EE documentation, and I also created an issue for the RE2 code that generates the error. Thanks.